# My pediatrician's office refuses to call for an authorization code (NJ) for pediatric bloodwork

Tags: medical, insurance

My son is 3.5 years old and has autism - he has a script for bloodwork from pediatrician. The location I found specializes in children with special needs (out of network)/ (he has been to this hospital but not this dept.) insurance -  NJ Horizon Health / medicaid. The office requires an authorization code to see my son - CAN HIS PEDIATRICIAN REFUSE THIS?

Why can't I try to give him to the best possible care? He may be denied but he may also be able to get the service. Can she refuse to call for authorization?

They want name to go to the unprofessional Labcorp (local) and when I called they don't even have a tech that works with pediatric blood drawing! please any and all  info welcome.

Comment: Is it possible that "calling for authorization" would require your pediatrician to assert that it's medically necessary for your son to go to the specialized lab, and that she doesn't consider that it is?

Comment: Thank you Nate. It is possible. I have to call again and get a concrete reason. I have to advocate for my little guy. He gets beyond upset with regular immunizations (thrashing - wailing etc) I need to find someone I feel safe with.

Answer (score 2):

There is a federal law, the [Emergency Medical Treatment and Active Labor Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_Medical_Treatment_and_Active_Labor_Act) which legally compels an emergency room (provided that they accept Medicare payments) to provide a medical screening examination and stabilize the patient. This is outside the scope of your concern. Otherwise, doctors have the same right to refuse to serve a customer that anyone other business has. Typically, when a business has good reason to believe that a person will breach their contract by not paying for a product or service, they have the right to refuse service. Authorization codes exists to remove the guesswork: it indicates that the insurance carrier has refused to cover some treatment.

Whether or not the insurance company can legally refuse to pay for a certain treatment, or stipulate what providers can provide the treatment, depends on the contract you have with the insurance provider.